# Steps to setup a new 3D Printer

Tags: prusa-i3, 3d-models, software, calibration, geeetech

I hope it doesn't get closed since my question is widely open:

I got recently a Geeetech Prusa i3 Pro B as a DIY kit, the assembly took a lot of time since the package did not include a building instruction. However the booklet contained a link to YouTube where I found almost all steps (based on the video names, some videos where missing and two steps had the wrong order).

I'm still wondering how I can put the (much too long) cables to prevent that they will touch the heat bed. Are there any hints or best practices?

However now the axes can be moved from the top panel however I'm not sure how to adjust the printer. I already found out the deltas of each stepper (I just excluded the extruder for now). **How can I enter those deltas?**

When done the next logical step is to do some test print. However how!? I found no exact steps. **What kind of kind of printing software do I need?** (I'm running Windows OS) The device is detected as com port when I plug it in my computer. **Where do I find an ideal test 3d model?**

Sorry for so many questions, however I hope this can get a introduction for newbies like me.

Comment: Try to split the questions into multiple questions. This might help to get answers.

Comment: Please split this up, leave this question to answer the deltas question. What do you actually mean by that? Please expand by [edit]. Furthermore , the latter 2 question already have an answer at 3D Printing.SE. A valid substitution may be (in a new question): "I found this model, is this an ideal test model to test my new 3D printer".

Comment: As a side note, please provide the part of the construction manual you have problems with.